# В консоли появилась ошибка: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression. Nothing to repeat

Tags: javascript

В консоли появилась ошибка, хотя до этого все работало замечательно.

> Pattern attribute value +7 ([0-9]{3}) [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} is
>   not a valid regular expression: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular
>   expression: /+7 ([0-9]{3}) [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/: Nothing to
>   repeat

В чем может быть причина?

Comment: в неэкранированном плюсе

Comment: Примечание не совсем в тему, но зато объясняет случающиеся иногда тормоза Если в данном поле предварительно проводится фильтрация вводимых данных только на индийские/арабские цифры, то \d будет работать несколько быстрее, чем [0-9], если не проводится - то наоборот, медленнее, за счёт того, что в Юникоде цифрами считаются также разнообразные латинские, иероглифические и прочеазиатские значки, что приводит к более долгой отработке регекспа

Answer (score 3):

Символ `+` является специальным, в регулярных выражениях. Он обозначает, что группа/символ перед ним повторяет один и более раз.

Для того, чтобы его использовать в качестве обычного символа, его нужно экранировать с помощью обратного слэша `\`.

Конечное регулярное выражение может выглядеть так:

```
/\+7 ([0-9]{3}) [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/
```